# What did a wine gauger do in the 1900s?

Tags: historical-research, family

I am researching my family tree to create a Christmas present for my dad. I ordered my grandad's birth certificate and his father's occupation is listed as 'wine gauger of 48 Cheetham Street Manchester'. The year is 1916.

I have undertaken some research into what a wine gauger is - something to do with customs charges.

Is anybody able to provide any more detail about what this job entails? Would it have been seen as a good job to have?

Comment: " Wine gaugers were
employed to measure the contents of barrels. " [Wine gauger in Antwerp](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82089192.pdf)